# How to compare/match string column which is not having 100% same value in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have Jobs table:

| Job | Title | EndOfMonth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 36950704 | Senior Full Stack Developer (React Native) | 2022-01-31 |
| 36953479 | Senior Full Stack Developer (React Native) 2 | 2022-01-31 |
| 36953482 | Senior Full Stack Developer (React) 3 | 2022-01-31 |
| 37131847 | Senior Software Developer (.NET Core, Angular) | 2022-03-31 |
| 37132156 | Senior Software Developer (.NET Core, Angular) 2 | 2022-03-31 |
| 37132174 | Senior Software Developer (.NET Core, Angular) 3 | 2022-03-31 |
| 37132177 | Senior Software Developer (.NET Core, Angular) 4 | 2022-03-31 |
| 37309773 | Senior Software Developer (FinTech) | 2022-05-31 |
| 37309830 | Senior Software Developer (FinTech) 2 | 2022-05-31 |
| 37116394 | Senior .NET Developer (Windows Forms) | 2022-03-31 |

In this table, for each EndOfMonth, we have multiple jobs (openings) for a title. Titles do not match exactly, for example for 2022-01-31, there are 3 related jobs (openings)

- Senior Full Stack Developer (React Native)
- Senior Full Stack Developer (React Native) 2
- Senior Full Stack Developer (React) 3

Desired output is this:

| Job | Title | EndOfMonth | Related Job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 36950704 | Senior Full Stack Developer (React Native) | 2022-01-31 | 36950704 |
| 36953479 | Senior Full Stack Developer (React Native) 2 | 2022-01-31 | 36950704 |
| 36953482 | Senior Full Stack Developer (React) 3 | 2022-01-31 | 36950704 |
| 37131847 | Senior Software Developer (.NET Core, Angular) | 2022-03-31 | 37131847 |
| 37132156 | Senior Software Developer (.NET Core, Angular) 2 | 2022-03-31 | 37131847 |
| 37132174 | Senior Software Developer (.NET Core, Angular) 3 | 2022-03-31 | 37131847 |
| 37132177 | Senior Software Developer (.NET Core, Angular) 4 | 2022-03-31 | 37131847 |
| 37309773 | Senior Software Developer (FinTech) | 2022-05-31 | 37309773 |
| 37309830 | Senior Software Developer (FinTech) 2 | 2022-05-31 | 37309773 |
| 37116394 | Senior .NET Developer (Windows Forms) | 2022-03-31 | 37116394 |

Comment: How do know which of the 3 (or 4, or more) of the related jobs' code to report in the new column?

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks a lot for the response. There are multiple scenarios, let me confirm and I will come back to you in a moment.

Comment: I have partially fixed my answer.  It would still fail for the first 3 jobs (Senior Full Stack Developer (React Native) etc.) because it isn't clear what the rule is for knowing that these 3 are all the same group.

Comment: Hey Tim, did you ran it at your end. For first 3 jobs, you are right. But its not even working for other jobs as well... Can you please run it at your end? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a regex substring to include the job name up to and including term in parentheses, to allow us to group together common jobs.  Then use `MIN()` as an analytic function report the earliest job ID.

```sql
SELECT Job, Title, EndOfMonth,
       MIN(Job) OVER (PARTITION BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(Title, '.*\\(.*?\\)')) AS RelatedJob
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the response, let me test it and I will come back to you in a moment. Thanks

Comment: Hi Tim, I ran this code. But it is grouping Senior Software Developer (FinTech) JOBS and Senior Software Developer (.NET Core, Angular) JOBS. Both are different. I think, in regex_replace you are replacing even the bracket part. How can we avoid only the number which is present at the end of Title like 2,3,4,5... These numbers only..?